# how to get an array of numbers after a specific word or string in a txt file and get the line umber of this

Tags: matlab

i have a txt file that has very sentence and i want to get the numbers after 'x=' as an array,for example:

"Mechanical engineering is the discipline that applies engineering, physics, engineering mathematics, and materials science principles to design, analyze, manufacture, and maintain mechanical systems.
 It is one of the oldest and broadest of the engineering disciplines.

x= 12.35 3.1 4.2 8.21 5.25 5.5 4.65 6.87 0.25 2.0 "

please help me , i want to get the numbers as an array and get the line number of this sentence.

Comment: Its really hard to understand what you want to do and how you got the numbers in the examples!

Comment: What is the relation between the sentence and the numbers that you have shown?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, assuming that in the "x=..." line that "=" should only occur once and that no unrelated words appear on that same line, you can write something like the following

```
filename = "thisFile.txt";
equalsOccurrence = [];
fileID = fopen(filename);
nextLine = fgetl(fileID);
afterEquals = "";
lineNumber = 1;
while ischar(nextLine) && (afterEquals == "")
   lineOccurrence = strfind(nextLine, "=");
   if length(lineOccurrence) == 1
       afterEquals = nextLine(lineOccurrence+1:end);
   end
   nextLine = fgetl(fileID);
   lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;
end
fclose(fileID);
arrayOfNumbers = split(strip(afterEquals), ' ');
```

It basically searches the file line by line, and if it finds exactly one "=" on the line, it will store the contents of the line after that character, and split it into an array based on occurrences of " ".